# popoverview on textview click in tableview cell

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UITableView` as a form which has `UITextView` on the `UITableViewCell`.
I want the `UIPopoverView` to appear when the textview is selected in the position of the text view.
The `UIPopoverView` appears in different location when i click on the textview.
Please help me anyone if you can.
I am stuck in this part of the code from long time.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide some code. I think something wrong with arrow directions. Which arrow direction do you set?

Comment: If you want it to appear so that it occludes the text view rect, then call present from rect with a rectangle that is offset above the text view you had just clicked on.

Comment: this is iPhone application or iPad??

Comment: show the code so that you can easily get help.

Comment: Use>> [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:tableviewCell.frame inView:tblView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourPopoverView presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(yourTextView.frame.origin.x.0,yourTextView.frame.origin.x, 400.0, 400.0) 
                             inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                           animated:YES];
```

in above give frame with your requirement like yourTaxtView.Frame